# HTML5 + CSS: DIV floating left and right

Tags: css, html

I am trying to obtain the following responsive layout

[DIVs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2KEf.png)

with no luck. Can someone please help me ?
DIV1 has width = 100%,
DIV 2, DIV3 and DIV4 have all float:left while DIV5 has float:right; but the layout that I achieve is wrong :(

Comment: Please improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello, could you create a snippet with your html+css code to show us the issue?

Comment: Any specific reason why you are not using grid layout here?

Comment: place DIV5 before the DIV4 to force float right

Answer (score 0):

My attempt to create the image using flexbox.

https://codepen.io/goughjo02/pen/GBLdXW

N.B. instead of `float: right;`, you can use `margin-left: auto;` - that has the effect of automatically allocating all free space to the left of the div.

Answer (score 0):

### There you go!

I followed your picture.

```css
#wrap {
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:thin;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height:50px;
  min-width:100%
  display: flow-root;
}

#innerwrap{
  display: inline-grid;
}

.div_left {  
  min-width:150px;
  max-width:150px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:thin;
  text-align:center;
  float:left;
  margin:5px 10px 5px 10px;
  padding: 15px;
}

#div2 {  
  min-width:150px;
  max-width:150px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:thin;
  text-align:center;
  float:left;
  padding: 50px 15px 50px 15px;
}

#right {
  min-width:150px;
  max-width:150px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:thin;
  text-align:center;
  float: right;
  margin-top:5px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
Div1
<div id="wrap">
<div id="div2">Div2</div>

<div id="innerwrap">
<div class="div_left">Div3</div>
<div class="div_left">Div4</div>
</div>

<div id="right">Div5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mr.Jones I am happy to help in CSS and HTML5. :)